# Does this PHP code open up a website to SQL Injection

Tags: php, sql, security, sql-injection

I'm working on a web app and I came across this code snippit

```
$email=$_POST['email'];
$pass=$_POST['pass'];
$pass=md5($pass);
$query=mysql_real_escape_string($email,$link);
//echo $query."<br>";
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT pass FROM users WHERE email='".$email."'",$link);
if($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
```

I think the programmer intended `$query=mysql_real_escape_string($email,$link);` to be `$email=mysql_real_escape_string($email,$link);`

Do I have the right idea here?

Comment: Don't use MD5; it's not a secure hash.

Comment: @Slaks, I know MD5 isn't industry standard any more, but what exactly are the risks of someone using breaking it?  Is Md5 bad enough to break an arbitrary hash? If I had a legacy system that used it I wouldn't be particularly concerned but I could be wrong here and would like to know!

Comment: Yes, MD5 is bad enough to break an arbitrary hash. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5#Security "A collision attack exists that can find collisions within seconds on a computer with a 2.6Ghz Pentium4 processor."

Comment: stored pass = sha256(pass + username + salt) where salt is some secret password that only the code knows (through configuration.) - all 3, because two people with the same password will not have the same hash if you also use the username.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you're absolutely right - just correct that part, like you said, by changing it to

```
 $email = mysql_real_escape_string($email, $link);
```

, and that will protect against SQL injection there.

On a side note, I suggest you use `hash("sha512", xxx)` instead of `md5` because MD5 is becoming obsolete. If your column size doesn't allow for that though and you don't have the ability to change it, it's still OK.

Comment: Again with the DBDs? Am I a target now?

Comment: sorry I down voted because this doesn't answer the question asked, he was asking about SQL injection not general hash strength.   There is an SQL injection vulnerability here, and it's in the values passed directly into the SQL string.   It might cause confusion for people reading this question and answer as they are quite different problems.  I've removed the downvote anyway now because apparently using Md5 is a lot worse than I thought!

Comment: @Tom Gullen: My first sentence just said that the OP is right - that is a vulnerability, and the fix they suggested is correct. Sorry for not being clear, I'll edit.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `$email` is set, but then not filtered, it's used directly in the query.  As you pointed out, it looks like an error as the filtered value is not being used in the query.

Answer (score 1):

to prevent from blind SQL , wrap your POST data with tow more filters:

```
$email = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags(stripslashes($email)), $link)
```